# contentSize of UITextView doesn't change when push UIViewController in landscape

Tags: iphone

I have UIViewController's view with UITableView. Custom UITableViewCell consists of two halfs: 1.question(UILabel) and 2.answer(UITextView).

Yes, I know that UITextView is very 'heavy' control but I want to recognize phone numbers and automatically return back to app after phone call ends.

1-st question: are there any other solution(without using UITextView) to achieve such behavior?
Solution: custom UILabel + "tel://" url - don't work, it doesn't come back me to the app.

On top of this I want display disclose indicator when answer is longer than 2 lines. Since UITextView doesn't have property which tells haw many lines text has, I am calculating the count of text lines: `textView.contentSize.height / textView.font.lineHeight;`

2-nd question: When contentSize of UITextView is updated? I faced with problem, when push UIViewController in landscape mode, contentSize has default(Portrait) values.

Answer (score 0):

For Discription Button Use Below Given Line OF Code

[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton];

And For Calling Facility I haven't Found that You can Return to the application if you will get tell me about that.

And For Size Update Problem Use Detail View When Click On Discriptor Button And Use Label And When Click On Button In Detail View Put TextView For Detail Description Of More Then @ line...

I think This May Help you.....